# Boto Making Request on Behalf of Someone Else

Tags: boto

I have an account which I registered as an amazon developer. (Let's call this the `developer` account)

I have another account which I am treating as the seller account (also an amazon developer account). (Let's call this `seller` account)

I want my `developer` account to make requests to amazon on behalf of the `seller`.

So `seller` calls my `developer` app, which talks to Amazon.

According to the terms and conditions, I must use the `developer's` access and secret key.

I have given my `seller` the `developer` ID and I have a `Seller Id`, `Marketplace Id`, and a `MWS Auth Token`.

However, I'm not sure how to get a `MWSConnection` working since it appears `boto` doesn't have a parameter for entering the `MWS Auth Token`

I have tried.

```
access_key_id = developer_access_key_id
secret_key = developer_secret_key
seller_id = seller_id
MWSConnection(access_key_id, secret_key, SellerId=seller_id)
```

This results in a failure of `AccessDenied`

Is there a way to get this working, where I (the `developer`) can make a request on behalf of someone else (the `seller`)?

Comment: Are you trying to use MWS in NA or another country? Also, are you using boto2 or boto3

Answer (score 1):

## Some things that may not be your problem, but might be

A couple of stabs at what may be your problems before a more explicit solution:

1. `boto3` doesn't support MWS. If you're using it, it will not work. Use `boto`
2. `MWS` in regions that are not North America (`NA`) require additional configuration that you may not be providing

## What your problem probably is...

You're coming in and trying to set the SellerID in the args of MWS with:

`MWSConnection(access_key_id, secret_key, SellerId=seller_id)`

You should probably be doing it like this instead:

```py
from boto import mws

from boto.mws.connection import MWSConnection
accessKey = developer_access_key_id # Python prefers camelCase
secretKey = developer_secret_key    # Python prefers camelCase
merchantID = "XXXXXXXXXX"           # You never specified this

mws = MWSConnection(accessKey, secretKey)
mws.Merchant = merchantID
mws.SellerId = merchantID
```

While it is possible to pass in the SellerId through a keyword argument I believe that you have to specify *all* the named arguments unless you know what their explicit order is.

Arguments to a python function are essentially a dictionary and python just does some convenience for you to line up the order of invocation with the order of declaration. That's why you can be explicit and use `argumentName = argumentValue, ...` in *any order* in the invocation and still have your function work.